# Add total value according to chapter

Tags: javascript

I return a dynamic form where the products are separated by chapters.
In the example I put there are 3 different chapters.
At the end of each chapter, I intend to create an input with the total value of each chapter.

I'm doing it this way:

```js
var data = [
   {Designacao: "Micro-ondas1", NumCap:  "1", Capitulo: "Cozinha", NumSub: "1.1", Valor: "300", },
   {Designacao: "Exaustor cinzento 1", NumCap: "", Capitulo: "", NumSub: "1.2",  Valor: "75.00", },
   {Designacao: "Mesa - Castanha -8 Lugares", NumCap: "2", Capitulo: "Sala", NumSub: "2.1",  Valor: "741.00" },
   {Designacao: "Castanhas douradas",  NumCap: "", Capitulo: "", NumSub: "2.2",  Valor: "150.00", },
   {Designacao: "cama", NumCap: "3", Capitulo: "Quarto", NumSub: "3.1",  Valor: "485.00", },
   {Designacao: "Guarda Vestidos", NumCap: "", Capitulo: "", NumSub: "3.2",  Valor: "685.00", },
];

var linha = ``;
var soma = 0;
Object.keys(data).forEach(i=>{

Designacao = data[i].Designacao;
NumCap = data[i].NumCap;
Capitulo = data[i].Capitulo;
NumSub = data[i].NumSub;
Valor = data[i].Valor;
teste = parseInt(Valor);

if( NumCap > 0){
   soma += teste;
}

if(NumCap > 1){

linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-1" style="float: right;">  
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${soma}">
          <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Valor">Total</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;
}

if(!NumCap.length||!Capitulo.length){

linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-2" style="display: none;">                      
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${NumCap}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span> 
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Capitulo">Nº Capitulo</label>        
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4" style="display: none;">                      
          <input type="text" class="form-control1" value="${Capitulo}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span> 
          <span class="form-bar"></span>  
          <label class="label1 logo8" for="Capitulo">Capitulo</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;
}else{
linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-2">   
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${NumCap}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Capitulo">Nº Capitulo</label>        
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4"> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control1" value="${Capitulo}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span> 
          <span class="form-bar"></span> 
          <label class="label1 logo8" for="Capitulo">Capitulo</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;
}

linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${NumSub}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span> 
          <span class="form-bar"></span> 
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Capitulo1">Nº</label>        
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">  
          <textarea class="area2" rows="1" data-min-rows="1">${Designacao}</textarea>
          <span class="form-highlight"></span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span> 
          <label class="label1 logo8" for="Designaca">Designação</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-1">  
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${Valor}">
          <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Valor">Total</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;
}) 

linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-1" style="float: right;">  
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${soma}">
          <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Valor">Total</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;

$("#retorc6").html(linha);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" action="#!" id="retorc6">
</form>
```

The problem is that the total value of each chapter is being returned incorrectly. In chapter 1 the total value must be 375.00, in chapter 2 of 891.00 and in chapter 3 of 1170.00.

I'm not able to create the correct condition to return the values ​​as I want, can someone help to solve the problem?

The idea is to create, at the end of each chapter, the total value of the products in that same chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just moved the `soma += teste` to the end, and added a check to reset it after every 'chapter'.

The code below should work.

```js
var data = [
   {Designacao: "Micro-ondas1", NumCap:  "1", Capitulo: "Cozinha", NumSub: "1.1", Valor: "300", },
   {Designacao: "Exaustor cinzento 1", NumCap: "", Capitulo: "", NumSub: "1.2",  Valor: "75.00", },
   {Designacao: "Mesa - Castanha -8 Lugares", NumCap: "2", Capitulo: "Sala", NumSub: "2.1",  Valor: "741.00" },
   {Designacao: "Castanhas douradas",  NumCap: "", Capitulo: "", NumSub: "2.2",  Valor: "150.00", },
   {Designacao: "cama", NumCap: "3", Capitulo: "Quarto", NumSub: "3.1",  Valor: "485.00", },
   {Designacao: "Guarda Vestidos", NumCap: "", Capitulo: "", NumSub: "3.2",  Valor: "685.00", },
];

var linha = ``;
var soma = 0;
Object.keys(data).forEach(i=>{

Designacao = data[i].Designacao;
NumCap = data[i].NumCap;
Capitulo = data[i].Capitulo;
NumSub = data[i].NumSub;
Valor = data[i].Valor;
teste = parseInt(Valor);


if(NumCap > 1){

  linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-1" style="float: right;">  
            <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${soma}">
            <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
            <span class="form-bar"></span>
            <label class="label3 logo8" for="Valor">Total</label>        
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;
  }

if(!NumCap.length||!Capitulo.length){

linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-2" style="display: none;">                      
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${NumCap}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span> 
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Capitulo">Nº Capitulo</label>        
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4" style="display: none;">                      
          <input type="text" class="form-control1" value="${Capitulo}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span> 
          <span class="form-bar"></span>  
          <label class="label1 logo8" for="Capitulo">Capitulo</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;
}else{
linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-2">   
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${NumCap}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Capitulo">Nº Capitulo</label>        
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4"> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control1" value="${Capitulo}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span> 
          <span class="form-bar"></span> 
          <label class="label1 logo8" for="Capitulo">Capitulo</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;
}

linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${NumSub}">
          <span class="form-highlight"></span> 
          <span class="form-bar"></span> 
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Capitulo1">Nº</label>        
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">  
          <textarea class="area2" rows="1" data-min-rows="1">${Designacao}</textarea>
          <span class="form-highlight"></span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span> 
          <label class="label1 logo8" for="Designaca">Designação</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-1">  
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${Valor}">
          <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Valor">Total</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;

if (NumCap !== '') soma = 0;
soma += teste;
})

linha += `<div class="form-group col-md-1" style="float: right;">  
          <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" value="${soma}">
          <span class="form-highlight">€</span>
          <span class="form-bar"></span>
          <label class="label3 logo8" for="Valor">Total</label>        
          </div>
          <div style="clear:both;"></div>`;
          

$("#retorc6").html(linha);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" action="#!" id="retorc6">
</form>
```